# How does Minotaur fit into the world of "Battle Circle" by Piers Anthony?

Tags: piers-anthony

TVTropes says:

> In Battle Circle by Piers Anthony, the heroine is trapped **in a Minotaur's maze**. The hero goes in to rescue her. He finds her but they are unable to escape and the Minotaur is closing in on them.

However, [Wikipedia's article on The Battle Circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Circle_%28novels%29) seems to offer absolutely no clue as to what a Minotaur of a Greek mythology would be doing in post-apocalyptic North America?

> he novels take place on a post-apocalyptic Earth. The history is not given in detail, but the landscape is filled with the ruins of the previous civilization, and large areas (referred to as the "badlands") are still deadly because of radiation, presumably from nuclear war. In North America, there are three main civilizations: the crazies, the underworlders, and the nomads, who are the main focus of the novels.

I haven't read the novels yet, so I'm curious how Minotaur fits with the setting. Is it some weird mutant? Or one of the members of the 3 civilizations mentioned by Wiki who has nothing to do with half-man-half-bull Greek thing? Why would someone build a maze for it? Basically, what's the backstory?

There doesn't seem to be a Wikia for this universe, and Googling didn't bring up anything terribly useful except for one item - the "[Nuclear Holocausts: Atomic War in Fiction" essay/book](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/nuclear/4chap.htm) implies that it was a mutant, but has zero context or details.

<sub>Feel free to spoil as much as you wish as far as I'm concerned, but please consider using spoiler markup for the sake of other readers.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without going into too much detail (partially because I haven't read them in years, and don't remember too much) in the future

> although it's post-apocolyptic, there exists a society of scientists who stay (literally) underground, and are not known of by the common man. They maintain control of the world from 'Behind the Scenes' and many facets of the society are what they have introduced as a way of keeping the common man under control. I believe they created the minotaur as one of their experiments, as he mentions being basically the Bugaboo that keeps many in line in his part of the world.

**EDIT**
Ok; I just dug up my copy.  Although the minotaur refers to himself as a god, he also says

> "The temple produced me by mutation and operation-"

and later, when talking about his needs/urges

> "That is the way I have been designed;"

So, there ya go -- straight from the Minotaur's mouth.

Answer (score 0):

He is a created being, clearly a retro-reference by a post-apocalyptic society attempting to rebuild itself, referring back to classical sources for lessons learned.

The city-state in which Var and Soli find themselves is New Crete in the Aleutian Islands, and they patterned their post-apocalyptic civilization after that of the Minoan civilization, hence their "god", Minos.

Comment: As this question has an accepted answer from a year ago, do you have any references or text to cite? Anything to improve upon that answer? I suggest checking out the [Tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how to ask and answer questions. We're not a typical discussion forum. *Don't be discouraged, we were all new here at some point.*